# DocumentClient.CreateDatabaseQuery - No definition exists

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to follow the azure DocumentDb quick start project.  The app I will be developing will be in WPF rather than the console, so to ramp up on documentdb I created a new wpf project (.Net 4.5.1) but I get the following error:

**'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDatabaseQuery' and no extension method 'CreateDatabaseQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I used the following command to install the azure documentdb client:

**Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client -Pre**

This is the code that is giving me the issue (lifted straight from the quick start tutorial):

```
            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("endpoint"), "authKey");    
            var db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery()
                            .Where(d => d.Id == databaseId)
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is the contents of my Nuget Packages.config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client" version="0.9.1-preview" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Anybody any ideas what I'm missing?  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Premium Update 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are missing the `using` directive for the DocumentDB Linq provider (`Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq`). Please make sure you have the following directives to the top of your .cs file:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents; 
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;
```

Comment: CreateDatabaseQuery and other methods are extension methods as explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient_members.aspx. They apply to DocumentClient, but they are implemented in other classes (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryable in this case)

Comment: Where I can found those dll files !

Comment: You can grab them by downloading the .NET Client SDK off Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/